# Python pandas - Aggregate values in separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, aggregate

I am new in Python and I was wondering if somebody can help me with the below task.

I am having the below dataframe df with the following columns:

- Primary ID
- Secondary ID
- Entity type
- Value

Each primary entity (Entity type: A) might consist of some secondary entities (Entity types; X or Y). For entity types A, the primary id is the same with the secondary id. Also, each primary entity and each secondary entity have a value.

In columns 'Sum of values Secondary id X' and 'Sum of values Secondary id Y', I want to have the aggregate value of the secondary entities (X and Y) which correspond to each primary entity. The aggregate values should be in the row of the primary entity.

So,  my initial df is this:

| Primary ID | Secondary ID | Entity type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0109 | 0109 | A | 200 |
| 0109 | A234 | X | 100 |
| 0109 | A234 | X | 50 |
| 9996 | 9996 | A | 400 |
| 9996 | AAGT | X | 120 |
| 9996 | AABG | X | 30 |
| 9996 | 0082 | Y | 50 |
| A765 | A765 | A | 50 |

And I just want to add the 2 columns, without changing the format of the initial dataframe:

| Primary ID | Secondary ID | Entity type | Value | Sum of values Secondary id X | Sum of values Secondary id Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0109 | 0109 | A | 200 | 150 | 0 |
| 0109 | A234 | X | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 0109 | A234 | X | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| 9996 | 9996 | A | 400 | 150 | 50 |
| 9996 | AAGT | X | 120 | 0 | 0 |
| 9996 | AABG | X | 30 | 0 | 0 |
| 9996 | 0082 | Y | 50 | 0 | 0 |
| A765 | A765 | A | 50 | 0 | 0 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try creating dict using:

```
(df.groupby(['Primary ID', 'Entity type'])['Value']      
        .sum()    
        .unstack(-1)                    
        .fillna(0).reset_index()                      
        )
```

---

```
Entity type Primary ID  A   X       Y
0           0109    200.0   150.0   0.0
1           9996    400.0   150.0   50.0
2           A765    50.0    0.0     0.0
```

---

The above data can be converted into a dict and then you can map.

**Complete solution:**

```
map_df = (df.groupby(['Primary ID', 'Entity type'])['Value']      
        .sum()    
        .unstack(-1)                    
        .fillna(0).reset_index()                      
        ).drop(['A'], axis=1).set_index('Primary ID')
```

---

```
df.set_index('Primary ID', inplace=True)
df.loc[df['Entity type'].eq('A'),['new_x', 'new_y']] = map_df.values
```

---

**df:**

|  | Secondary ID | Entity type | Value | new_x | new_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Primary ID |  |  |  |  |  |
| 0109 | 0109 | A | 200 | 150.0 | 0.0 |
| 0109 | A234 | X | 100 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 0109 | A234 | X | 50 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 9996 | 9996 | A | 400 | 150.0 | 50.0 |
| 9996 | AAGT | X | 120 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 9996 | AABG | X | 30 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| 9996 | 0082 | Y | 50 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| A765 | A765 | A | 50 | 0.0 | 0.0 |

Answer (score 0):

First solution is used first by replace `Value`s by missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then for new columns is used [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), last replace duplicates by `0` in [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
cols = ['Sum of values Secondary id X','Sum of values Secondary id Y']
df[cols] = (df.assign(x = df['Value'].where(df['Entity type'].eq('X')),
                      y = df['Value'].where(df['Entity type'].eq('Y')))
              .groupby('Primary ID')[['x','y']]
              .transform('sum')
              .mask(df['Primary ID'].duplicated(), 0)
              .astype(int))
print (df)
  Primary ID Secondary ID Entity type  Value  Sum of values Secondary id X  \
0       0109         0109           A    200                           150   
1       0109         A234           X    100                             0   
2       0109         A234           X     50                             0   
3       9996         9996           A    400                           150   
4       9996         AAGT           X    120                             0   
5       9996         AABG           X     30                             0   
6       9996         0082           Y     50                             0   
7       A765         A765           A     50                             0   

   Sum of values Secondary id Y  
0                             0  
1                             0  
2                             0  
3                            50  
4                             0  
5                             0  
6                             0  
7                             0
```

If need all values to new columns use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='Primary ID', 
                    columns='Entity type', 
                    values='Value', 
                    aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
         .add_prefix('Sum of values Secondary id '))


df = df.join(df1, on='Primary ID')
df.loc[df['Primary ID'].duplicated(), df1.columns] = 0
print (df)
  Primary ID Secondary ID Entity type  Value  Sum of values Secondary id A  \
0       0109         0109           A    200                           200   
1       0109         A234           X    100                             0   
2       0109         A234           X     50                             0   
3       9996         9996           A    400                           400   
4       9996         AAGT           X    120                             0   
5       9996         AABG           X     30                             0   
6       9996         0082           Y     50                             0   
7       A765         A765           A     50                            50   

   Sum of values Secondary id X  Sum of values Secondary id Y  
0                           150                             0  
1                             0                             0  
2                             0                             0  
3                           150                            50  
4                             0                             0  
5                             0                             0  
6                             0                             0  
7                             0                             0
```

Comment: @Pygirl - yes, I guess same problem - somebody think my first solution is bad, so downvoted.